# Unable to login into WordPress 401

Tags: login

I am trying to login to my site but when i hit the root URL i get a pop says to login there but my wordpress username and passowrd never worked there nither i can get into wp-admin. Please kindly comment if you have the answer.Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd guess that's authentication added by your web server, not WordPress, so it probably will be a different password, yes. You'll have to look at your web server configuration, e.g. look for ['AuthType'](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PasswordBasicAuth) in Apache configuration or [auth_basic](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/) in NGINX, or talk to your host about this.

Comment: Yes, That was a server issue and i fixed it. Thanks for helping.